# Find the limit of $\int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln t} dt$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit of $G(x)=\int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln t} dt$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

(I tried to use the squeeze theorem, but I found this wich don't admit a limit at $0$ : $\frac {1}{t-1}\le \frac{1}{\ln t}\le \frac{t}{t-1}$ gives me $\ln(x^2-1) - \ln(x-1)\le \int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln t} dt \le \ln(x^2-1) - \ln(x-1) + x^2 - x$.)

Comment: Do you mean $x \to 0$ or $ x \to 1$?

Comment: I really mean $x \rightarrow 0$, that's why I'm stuck on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One has, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\left|\ln x\right| \to \infty, \qquad \left|\frac{1}{\ln x}\right| \to 0
$$ giving that, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\left|\int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln t} dt\right|\le \left|(x^2-x)\right|\cdot \left|\frac{1}{\ln x}\right|\to 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you, but I have a question : I don't understand why $\int_x^{x^2} \left|\frac{1}{\ln t}\right| dt \le  \left|(x^2-x)\right|\cdot \left|\frac{1}{\ln x}\right|\to 0.$?

Comment: @MiKiDe You are welcome. I've used the following result $$\left|\int_a^b f(t)\:dt\right|\le|a-b|\cdot M $$ where $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and $M=\sup_{t \in [a,b]}\left|f(t)\right|$. Here, for $0<x<1$, $M=\sup_{t \in [x,x^2]}\left|f(t)\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\ln x}\right|$.

Comment: Your inequalies are problematic since $x>x^2.$ Thus the integral as given is already positive for small $x>0, $ etc.

Comment: @zhw. Please, observe that the inequality is positive for *each* $0<x<1$, but the given integral *tends* to $0$ as $x \to 0^+$, which is not a contradiction...

Comment: $\int_x^{x^2} \left|\frac{1}{\ln t}\right| dt$ is negative.

Comment: @zhw. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We need to restrict to $x\to 0^+.$ Also note $x^2 < x$ for small positive $x.$ Recall that when $b<a,$ $\int_a^b f$ is defined to be $-\int_b^a f.$ With that in mind, observe that $ 0 <1/|\ln t| < 1$ for $0<t<1/e.$ So for $0<x<1/e,$

$$0 \le\int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln t} \, dt = - \int_{x^2}^x \frac{1}{\ln t} \, dt   = \int_{x^2}^{x} \left |\frac{1}{\ln t}\right| dt \le \int_{x^2}^{x} 1\, dt =x-x^2 \to 0.$$